# Using promises and continuations

Tags: javascript, promise

I have looked at many examples of `Promises` and `Continuations` but have not found a consistently working pattern.

Here is an attempt to use a pair of encryption related methods:

```
async function makeAesGcmKeys() {
    let key = await crypto.subtle.generateKey(
        {
            name: "AES-GCM",
            length: 256
        },
        true,
        ["encrypt", "decrypt"]
    );   
    let exported = key.then( k => { crypto.subtle.exportKey('raw',k)})
    return [key,exported]
}

makeAesGcmKeys().then((k,e) => { 
   console.log(`in continuation: exported=${e}`); 
   return [k,e]
}).then( (key,exported) => {
    console.log(`main: ${exported}`)
});
```

This results in a `Promise` being returned.  I need the resolved result not the `Promise`.  I have tried various permutations on the above but they also return a `Promise`.  Pointers appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried with `await key.then(...)`?

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek I added that and still do not see anything printed on Console

Comment: `.then()`'s callback takes only one argument. If you have returned `[key,exported]` in your function, then you need to treat `k` in `.then()` as an array. Try printing `k[1]` instead of `e` (while still having `await key.then(...)`).